# Semi-playable chess game in Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, chess

I made a simple, semi-playable command line Chess game for my class exercise.

At this point, this game can do the following things:

1. Print out the updated board representation after every move
2. Players can take turns
3. Players can actually move pieces

The code is pretty long so I don't really expect people to read all of it. However, if you can somehow skim through them and provide one quick feedback, I would be really grateful! I just started learning Ruby and really want to be conscious of how I arrange objects and follow the SOLID principle.

Besides that, I also have one quick question: Is it recommended to put a lot of functions within one function? Sometimes I put 5 or 6 functions within the initialization function of a class. I am worried that might cause some trouble in the future. However, if I don't do that, I will have to call those functions one by one in the main app.rb, which would make the code longer in the main app.rb. Which is generally better?

**App.rb**

```
require_relative("lib/input.rb")
require_relative("lib/Board.rb")
require_relative("lib/Chess.rb")
require_relative("lib/Rook.rb")
require_relative("lib/Pawn.rb")
require_relative("lib/King.rb")
require_relative("lib/Bishop.rb")
require_relative("lib/Knight.rb")
require_relative("lib/Queen.rb")




puts "Welcome to this boring Chess Game!"
puts "It is so boring. U sure u want to play? y/n "
enter_game = gets.chomp.upcase

puts "you don't have a choice" if enter_game == "N"
puts "-----------------------"
puts "-----------------------"
puts "X: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
puts "Y: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
puts "Sample input: 58 would be Black King(bKing)"
puts "-----------------------"
puts "-----------------------"



board1 = Board.new
board1.show



play_condition = true

while play_condition
    ori_cor = board1.ask_for_ori
    board_move_validity_ori = board1.check_board_valid(ori_cor)

    # a convert function might be more useful here because we are reusing it again and again and also it's pretty simple to set up

    # puts "value 0 #{index_x}"
    # puts index_y

    if !board_move_validity_ori
    #   puts "false condition"
        board1.prompt_valid
        next
    end
    #puts index_start_x
    #puts index_start_y
    des_cor = board1.ask_for_des
    board_move_validity_des = board1.check_board_valid(des_cor,1)

    if !board_move_validity_des
        board1.prompt_valid
        next
    end

    array_ori = board1.convert(ori_cor)
    array_des = board1.convert(des_cor)

    start_x = array_ori[0]
    start_y = array_ori[1]

    # obtaining x,y index from the string input
    index_start_x = array_ori[2]
    index_start_y = array_ori[3]

    final_x = array_des[0]
    final_y = array_des[1]

    index_final_x = array_des[2]
    index_final_y = array_des[3]

    #p array_ori
    #p array_des


    intended_piece = board1.grid[index_start_x][index_start_y]
    #puts "can move" if intended_piece.can_move?(final_x,final_y)
    #puts piece_name   # pice name obtained
    #puts intended_piece
    piece_move_validity = intended_piece.can_move?(final_x,final_y)
        #puts piece_move_validity

    if piece_move_validity == true
        puts "can move"
#       des_status = board1.check_empty(index_final_x,index_final_y)
#       if des_status == "empty"
        #puts "start moving"
        board1.move(intended_piece,index_start_x,index_start_y,index_final_x,index_final_y)
#       puts "call move function"
#       else
# #             compare
#           puts "call compare function"
#       end
    else
        board1.prompt_valid
    end

    board1.show

end
```

**Board.rb**

```
class Board
    include Input

    attr_reader :grid
    def initialize

        @turn = 0

        bR = Rook.new(1,8,"black","B5")
        bK = Knight.new(2,8,"black","B4")
        bB = Bishop.new(3,8,"black","B3")
        bQ = Queen.new(4,8,"black","B2")
        bKing = King.new(5,8,"black","B1")
        bB2 = Bishop.new(6,8,"black","B3")
        bK2 = Knight.new(7,8,"black","B4")
        bR2 = Rook.new(8,8,"black","B5")

        wR = Rook.new(1,1,"white","W5")
        wK = Knight.new(2,1,"white","W4")
        wB = Bishop.new(3,1,"white","W3")
        wQ = Queen.new(4,1,"white","W2")
        wKing = King.new(5,1,"white","W1")
        wB2 = Bishop.new(6,1,"white","W3")
        wK2 = Knight.new(7,1,"white","W4")
        wR2 = Rook.new(8,1,"white","W5")

        bP1 = Pawn.new(1,7,"black","BP")
        bP2 = Pawn.new(2,7,"black","BP")
        bP3 = Pawn.new(3,7,"black","BP")
        bP4 = Pawn.new(4,7,"black","BP")
        bP5 = Pawn.new(5,7,"black","BP")
        bP6 = Pawn.new(6,7,"black","BP")
        bP7 = Pawn.new(7,7,"black","BP")
        bP8 = Pawn.new(8,7,"black","BP")

        wP1 = Pawn.new(1,2,"white","WP")
        wP2 = Pawn.new(2,2,"white","WP")
        wP3 = Pawn.new(3,2,"white","WP")
        wP4 = Pawn.new(4,2,"white","WP")
        wP5 = Pawn.new(5,2,"white","WP")
        wP6 = Pawn.new(6,2,"white","WP")
        wP7 = Pawn.new(7,2,"white","WP")
        wP8 = Pawn.new(8,2,"white","WP")

        @grid = [
            [bR,bK,bB,bQ,bKing,bB2,bK2,bR2],
            [bP1,bP2,bP3,bP4,bP5,bP6,bP7,bP8],
            ["00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"],
            ["00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"],
            ["00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"],
            ["00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"],
            [wP1,wP2,wP3,wP4,wP5,wP6,wP7,wP8],
            [wR,wK,wB,wQ,wKing,wB2,wK2,wR2],    
        ]


    end

    def check_empty(final_x,final_y)
        if @grid[final_x][final_y] == "00"
            "empty"
        else
            @grid[final_x][final_y]
        end
    end


    def show
        puts "Current Board Status:"
        @grid.each do |row|
            row.each do |element|
                if element == "00"
                    print "|#{element}|"
                else
                    print "|#{element.name}|"
                end
            end
            print "\n"
        end
    end
    def prompt_valid
        puts "Plz input valid coordinates for the piece"
        puts "-----------------------"
        puts "-----------------------"
        puts "X: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
        puts "Y: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
        puts "Sample input: 58 would be B1 / Black King(bKing)"
        puts "-----------------------"
        puts "-----------------------"
    end

    def move piece, index_start_x, index_start_y, index_des_x, index_des_y
        #puts index_start_x,index_start_y,index_des_x,index_des_y
        #puts "destination original value #{@grid[index_des_x][index_des_y]}"
        #puts "destination become #{@grid[index_des_x][index_des_y].name}"
        #puts "original is #{@grid[index_des_x][index_des_y].name}"
        @grid[index_des_x][index_des_y] = piece.clone
        @grid[index_des_x][index_des_y].start_x = index_start_y + 1
        @grid[index_des_x][index_des_y].start_y = 8 - index_start_x
        @grid[index_start_x][index_start_y] = "00"
        if @turn ==1
            @turn = 0
        elsif @turn == 0
            @turn = 1
        end

    end

    def compare

    end
end
```

**Input.rb**

```
module Input
    def ask_for_ori

        puts "-------------------------"
        puts "-------------------------"

        if @turn ==0
            puts "White chess turn"
        else 
            puts "Black chess turn"
        end

        puts "Input the coordinates of the piece you want to move"
        puts "-------------------------"
        puts "------------------------"
        input_cor = gets.chomp
    end

    def ask_for_des
        puts "-------------"
        puts "Input the coordinates of the destination"
        input_des = gets.chomp
    end


    def check_board_valid(input_cor, des = 0) # whether input is within the range
        array1 = input_cor.split("") 

        if des == 0
            if (@grid[8-(array1[1].to_i)][(array1[0].to_i)-1].name =~ /[W]/ ) && @turn == 0
                puts "first con"
                true
            elsif (@grid[8-(array1[1].to_i)][(array1[0].to_i)-1].name =~ /[B]/) && @turn ==1
                puts "second con"
                true
            else
                puts "It's not your turn yet piece of shit"
                return false
            end
        end


        #puts @grid[8-(array1[1].to_i)][(array1[0].to_i)-1]
         if (1..8).include?(array1[0].to_i) && (1..8).include?(array1[1].to_i) && array1.length ==2
            if @grid[8-(array1[1].to_i)][(array1[0].to_i)-1] == "00" && des ==0
                puts "This slot has an empty piece.pls try again"
                return false
            end
            return true

         else
            return false
         end

    end

    def convert input_cor
        start_x = input_cor.split("")[0].to_i
        start_y = input_cor.split("")[1].to_i

        # obtaining x,y index from the string input
        index_start_x = 8 - start_y
        #puts "after math equal #{index_start_x}"

        index_start_y = start_x -1
        array1 = start_x,start_y,index_start_x,index_start_y
        #p array1
        #array1
    end

end
```

For the sake of not making this page looks too horrifying, other source code is included in [my git](https://github.com/kingofwhales/ironhack/tree/master/week1/day5). Please check it out if you have the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, some variable names can be more descriptive.

It looks like you're using tabs for indentation. It's convenient to use 2 spaces.
It's convenience to use single quotes if there is no interpolation in the string.

Constructions like that one:

```
if @x_diff <= 1 && @y_diff <= 1
  true
else
  false
end
```

Can be simplified to:

```
@x_diff <= 1 && @y_diff <= 1
```

You're using `@turn` for some kind of "flag" with two possible states. Why not to use true/false? That piece of code can be rewritten in more concise way:

```
if @turn == 1
  @turn = 0
elsif @turn == 0
  @turn = 1
end
```

Like that:

```
@turn = false
# ...
@turn = !@turn # now 1 is true and false is 0.
```

`"00"` is used for "placeholder" of empty square. It will be easier to use `false` or `nil`. And use `"00"` only for rendered part.
Updated `@grid` and `Board#show` can be rewritten in that way:

```
@grid = [
  [bR,bK,bB,bQ,bKing,bB2,bK2,bR2],
  [bP1,bP2,bP3,bP4,bP5,bP6,bP7,bP8],
  [nil] * 8,
  [nil] * 8,
  [nil] * 8,
  [nil] * 8,
  [wP1,wP2,wP3,wP4,wP5,wP6,wP7,wP8],
  [wR,wK,wB,wQ,wKing,wB2,wK2,wR2],  
]
#...

def show
  puts "Current Board Status:"
  @grid.each do |row|
    row.each { |element| print "|#{element ? element.name : '00'}|" }
    print "\n"
  end
end
```

`Board#check_board_valid` have bunch of responsibilities. It looks more like "functional-styled" code. Can be separated into simple methods:

```
def check_board_valid(input_cor, des = 0) # whether input is within the range
  input_cor = input_cor.split('').map(&:to_i)

  return unless coord_valid?(input_cor) # maybe add some message here

  figure = @grid[8 - input_cor.last)][input_cor.first - 1]

  return puts('This slot has an empty piece.pls try again') unless figure

  if des == 0 # this condition still can be simplified
    if whites_move?(figure)
      puts 'first con'
      true # probably, that line can be removed after overall refactoring
    elsif blacks_move?(figure)
      puts 'second con'
      true # probably, that line can be removed after overall refactoring
    else
      puts 'It\'s not your turn yet piece of shit'
      return false
    end
  end
end

private

def coord_valid?(input_cor)
  input_cor.size == 2 && input_cor.all? { |coord| (1..8).include?(coord) }
end

def whites_move?(figure)
  figure.is_white? && !@turn
end

def blacks_move?(input_cor)
  figure.is_black? && @turn
end

# at "lib/Chess.rb"
class Chess
#...
  def is_black?
    self.name =~ /[B]/
  end

  def is_white?
    self.name =~ /[W]/
  end
end
```

That's it for now. I hope, that you get the main idea.

Comment: Thank you. This is immensely helpful!   I was worried about calling too many methods inside one method before. That's why I give the function so many responsibilities so it doesn't have to depend on other things. But I just read that it's okay to call other methods in your class directly because it won't violate the principle of least knowledge.

Comment: Glad I could help, @whales!